# How to link ncurses in Visual Studio 2019 (WSL project)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hello I'm have a C++ (linux with WSL) project in Visual Studio 2019.

My first problem is I cannot `#include <ncurses.h>`.

The second part of my problem is I don't know how to setup the ncurses library with the linker.